# NSIS question : Can I disable the "Finish" button in "MUI_PAGE_FINISH" page when the ".onInstSuccess" function not finish?

Tags: nsis

I use NSIS to package my application, and I need to install some third party software, like .Net re-distribution, run-time engine in ".onInstSuccess" function. But after install finish, the "MUI_PAGE_FINISH" page will display and start to call ".onInstSuccess" function. If user click the finish button in "MUI_PAGE_FINISH" page when ".onInstSuccess" function still running, that will be not fully install third party software. Can I disable the finish button and re-enable it after ".onInstSuccess" function finished? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyFxn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should only install things in `Section`s! When the InstFiles page is done, your install should be fully functional. Make sure you are using `ExecWait` and the correct command line parameters (silent/wait etc.) when installing redistributable libraries.

`.onInstSuccess` is called after the last page and you are not really supposed to interact with the UI nor perform operations that take a long time.

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function .onInstSuccess
GetDlgItem $0 $hWndParent 1
EnableWindow $0 0
Messagebox mb_ok "Performing a long operation here even though you are not supposed to..."
EnableWindow $0 1
FunctionEnd
```